# Subset a dataframe base on part of a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains a column with 5 digit codes. I would like to be able to subset the data frame using only the first two digits of the code.

```
df <- data.frame(code=c("AA000", "AAA00", NA, "AA900", "A1234", "B0000",
                        "B1234", "B9999", "CC000", "CC123"),
                 data=c("Stuff AA000", "Stuff AAA00", "an NA", "Stuff AA900",
                       "Stuff A1234", "Stuff B0000", "Stuff B1234",
                       "Stuff B9999", "Stuff CC000", "Stuff CC123"))

# WUC   data
# AA000, Stuff AA000
# AAA00, Stuff AAA00
# AA900, Stuff AA900
# A1234, Stuff A1234
# B0000, Stuff B0000
# B1234, Stuff B1234
# B9999, Stuff B9999
# CC000, Stuff CC000
# CC123, Stuff CC123
```

While composing this question I came across [Remove part of a string in dataframe column (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277117/remove-part-of-a-string-in-dataframe-column-r) that suggested doing something like:

```
df[gsub("^(..).*","\\1",df$code) == "AA",]
#   WUC  data
# AA000, Stuff AA000
# AAA00, Stuff AAA00
# <NA>   <NA>
# AA900, Stuff AA900
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this. My end goal is a count of all the two digit codes: AA=3, B0=1, B1=1, B9=1, CC=2

Comment: `df[substr(df$code,1,2)=="AA",]` ? There is really no need for complicated regular expressions.

Comment: `table(substr(df$code, 1, 2))` for the counts.