# Need to remove some specific string from a column using R script

Tags: r

Below is the sample of the data in a column Region, i need to remove " (more info)" from the data.

1. Sri Lanka (more info)
2. Guyana (more info)
3. Mongolia
4. Kazakhstan (more info)
5. Suriname

Tried : `as.character(gsub( "[\\ (more info)]", "", States$Regions))-> abc` 
This is not giving proper result.

Expected Result:

1. Sri Lanka
2. Guyana
3. Mongolia
4. Kazakhstan
5. Suriname

Comment: @Gregor, Thanks `gsub( " \\(more info\\)", "", States$Regions)-> States$Regions` working fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove part of a string in dataframe column (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277117/remove-part-of-a-string-in-dataframe-column-r)

Comment: ** @Tjebo, This is not a duplicate**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong.

1) Don't use brackets here. In regex, `[abc]` matches `a` or `b` or `c`. You want to match the whole pattern, so don't use brackets. (You could use parenthesis, but it it not necessary

```
"\\ (more info)"  # fix 1: no brackets
```

2) You seem to know backslashes are used to escape things in regex. But they must be next to what they are escaping! Here you are escaping a space, which is meaningless. You need to escape both parentheses that are part of your pattern:

```
"\\(more info\\)"  # fix 2: escape parens
```

3) You still need the space, but it goes at the front, before the (escaped) parenthesis:

```
" \\(more info\\)"  # fix 3: space at beginning
```

Now the pattern should work. Also note that `gsub` returns a `character`, so your `as.character` is redundant.

I'd strongly recommend using a site like regex101.com to debug regex. You only need single `\` to escape there, but other than that it is just like R. [Here's your example](https://regex101.com/r/QZpiWt/1). Check out the sidebar for nice explanations.